# Should padding bytes be passed to glteximage2d

Tags: opengl

Title itself explains the question.
The last parameter of glTexImage2D is the array of bytes (unsigned, signed depends).

Should rgb array contain padding bytes  or not?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The short answer is no. I typically create an array of structures.

The structure would look like:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char red;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char blue;
    unsigned char alpha;
} AlphaPixelBytes;
```

Then the array I create would look like:

```
AlphaPixelBytes bitmapData[NUMTEXTUREPOINTS];
```

You can then use bitmapData as the last argument to glTexImage2D when you create the texture or you can pass NULL as the last argument to create an empty texture you'll later populate with glTexSubImage2D.

This sort of array of structures is also useful as a data source for an NSBitmapImageRep for use (for example) in exporting a PNG file of your texture.

EDIT:

Sorry, I didn't notice you're dealing with RGB not RGBA data.  The structure for RGB would look like:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char red;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char blue;
} PixelBytes;
```

And the array:

```
PixelBytes bitmapData[NUMTEXTUREPOINTS];
```

Comment: I didn't knew that we could use structs for arrays. But if it works then hats off.

Comment: I do it all the time.  You just need to get the array loaded in the right order, usually with a for i loop for 0 to TEXTUREWIDTH and inside that a for j loop for 0 to TEXTUREHEIGHT.

Comment: @jwlaughton: Well, you shouldn't do it, because the compiler is free so add padding between the elements in a struct, as long as the order of elements is preserved. While there are ways to force compilers to tightly pack elements, there is no standard way of doing it, and it should be avoided if its not absolutely necessary.

Comment: @datenwolf: I don't think I understand your point.  From the glPixelStore docs: Storage format GL_RGB, for example, has three components per pixel: first red, then green, and finally blue.  Fennekin should should be fine doing as I suggest as (I think) he uses a GL_RGB format.

Comment: @jwlaughton: `glPixelStore` is related to the packing and unpacking of pixel data, not really the storage (I guess it's a misleading name if you think about it). In any case, when you transfer pixel data to OpenGL by default, it is assumed that each row of the input image begins on a 4-byte boundary (unless you change the default pixel store state). That guarantee falls apart for 3-byte pixels with image widths that are not divisible by 4 and then you wind up with alignment issues.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Thanks for that.  I don't use 3 byte pixel formats much, and (looking back) whenever I did, the texture widths were always divisible by 4.  This is good information.

Answer (score 1):

> Should RGB array contain padding bytes or not?

That entirely depends on your needs. You can configure OpenGL to accept various data layouts. See the reference documentation of [glPixelStore](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glPixelStore.xml), the *unpack* parameters are what you should look at.

Padding bytes are normally found between between rows, to fill up to a certain alignment. The unpack alignment specifies the byte alignment of each *row*.

If your pixels are 8 bit per component, but packed into 4 bytes each with a padding byte, you can specify that, by declaring the data type to be `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8`; if you use a type/internal type with less than 4 components the excessive bytes are ignored.